# Show sum of coordinates squared less than or equal to norm squared

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

I'm trying to show that if $S = \{v_1, \dots, v_q\}$ is orthonormal, then for every $v$ in a vector space $V$ we have

$$
    \sum_{k=1}^q|\alpha_k|^2 \leq \Vert v \Vert_V^2
$$

where $\alpha_k = \langle v_k, v\rangle$.

Using Cauchy-Schwartz, I was able to show $\sum_{k=1}^q|\alpha_k|^2 \leq q\Vert v \Vert^2$, but that doesn't seem helpful. I have a hint to consider $w = \sum_{k=1}^q\alpha_kv_k$ and $\langle v, w \rangle$, but it's not clear to me how to use those.

Comment: You are aware of the fact that what you are trying to prove is [Bessel's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality), right?!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I wasn't, obviously, and now can find proofs of Bessel's inequality online, but how do I use the hint to prove the inequality?

Comment: You use the fact that $w$ is the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto the space spanned by the $v_k$'s. Therefore, $\|w\|\leqslant\|v\|$.